# Benefits of being relaxed after reading up on the morning

Tags: sleep, mental-health, physical-health

I want someone to help direct me to research (if there exists any) of the advantages both mental and physical of waking up in a relaxed manner. To contrast it we have scenario A where your alarm goes off you wake up late at 8 and then quickly brush bathe get dressed have breakfast and leave for office whereas we have scenario B where you wake up at 7 but do all your tasks slowly in a easy going and carefree manner and waste a lot of time in the process. I personally have felt better after adopting scenario B but i want to know how big the differences are generally and are they big enough to recommend someone else